# PDF rendering using CGContextDrawPDFPage : cannot find CropBox

Tags: objective-c, ipad, pdf, core-graphics

I need to display the content of PDF files that i receive from a Web Service.

My problem is that all PDF boxes returns the same value. Do you have any idea what can be wrong with the files i'm using ?

```
CGPDFPageRef drawPDFPageRef = CGPDFPageRetain( CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, 1) );
CGRect cropBoxRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(drawPDFPageRef, kCGPDFCropBox);
CGRect mediaBoxRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(drawPDFPageRef, kCGPDFMediaBox);
```

cropBoxRect = (0,0,595,842)
mediaBoxRect = (0,0,595,842)

When i display the PDF in a UIWebView the content is ok

This is the PDF rendered by a UIWebView

[image]

This is the PDF rendered by CGContextDrawPDFPage

[image]

Thanks for your help,
Vincent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That doesn't look like metadata, but rather like the media box was being used to crop the PDF instead of the crop box. In your code you probably have something like this:

```
  CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(ctx, kCGInterpolationHigh); 
  CGContextSetRenderingIntent(ctx, kCGRenderingIntentDefault); 
  CGContextSetRGBFillColor( ctx, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );
  CGContextFillRect( ctx, CGContextGetClipBoundingBox( ctx ));

  CGContextTranslateCTM( ctx, 0.0, self.bounds.size.height );
  CGContextScaleCTM( ctx, 1.0, -1.0 );
  CGAffineTransform pdfXfm = CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform( pdfPage, kCGPDFMediaBox, self.bounds, 0, true );
  CGContextConcatCTM( ctx, pdfXfm );
  CGContextDrawPDFPage( ctx, pdfPage );
```

Try using `kCGPDFCropBox` in `CGPDFGetPageDrawingTransform`, that could help

Comment: kCGPDFCropBox and kCGPDFMediaBox return the same CGRect, does it mean that the pdf i'm using has some issue ?

Comment: It could be, but I doubt it (UIWebView displays it correctly). If you have Acrobat Professional, open it there and have a look at the values of the different boxes (art box, media box, crop box, trim box), I rather think that this is the source of your problem. Also, if you don't understand the concept of the various boxes, look up media box or crop box on wikipedia, it explains all the various boxes pretty nicely

Comment: What I was thinking is, that this PDF's crop box and media box are not identical. Usually, when you print something to a PDF printer or export from OpenOffice, etc., the Media box (which is basically the area the media takes, including what you want to print, its crop and color marks) is the same as the Crop box (which is basically the area that whatever you want to print takes on the media). In cases where the document needs to be printed on a printing machine, the crop box would be quiet smaller than the media box to display the crop marks, as in your document.

Comment: Your PDF has crop marks (the ones on the four angles of the page) determining how the document is cropped inside the media and it has alignment marks (the ones that look like a bulls eye mark) that allow a printer to align the (usually) four color panes (Cyan, Magenta, Yellow and black) unto each other to give a color image, although that's kinda senseless since you only have one color in this PDF.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanations it helped me to solve the problem

Comment: I'm having the same issue, can you please tell me how did you solve it?

Comment: if you really have the same issue, try replacing kCGPDFMediaBox with kCGPDFCropBox

Answer (score 1):

I believe those markings are drawn outside the visible page area. Since you do not clip the content at page boundary, everything in the page content is displayed.
This code should help (before drawing the page):

```
CGContextAddRect(ctx, cropBoxRect);
CGContextClip(ctx);
```

This article shows how to display properly a PDF page on iOS: http://ipdfdev.com/2011/03/23/display-a-pdf-page-on-the-iphone-and-ipad/