# Pdf - MediaBox or CropBox

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, core-graphics

I'm having this problem:

[PDF rendering using CGContextDrawPDFPage : cannot find CropBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939551/pdf-rendering-using-cgcontextdrawpdfpage-cannot-find-cropbox)

but this question isn't actually answered. 
Recap: I'm having trouble showing one particular pdf file, crop marks are visible but not on Safari on another reader. I've tried to use `kCGPDFCropBox`  instead of `kCGPDFMediaBox`  in the rendering, but resulting rects have the same values. Same result with `kCGPDFTrimBox`, example:

```
CGRect pageRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(pdfPage, kCGPDFMediaBox);
```

UPDATE:

```
origin=(x=0, y=0) size=(width=595, height=842)
```

for pageRect with `kCGPDFMediaBox` and

```
origin=(x=42.9783, y=61.4606) size=(width=511.299, height=719.97)
```

for pageRect with `kCGPDFCropBox`

Using the second one, the page is cropped, but not how I wanted to (leaving print and crop marks and cutting content). Other viewers still works fine with this file

Comment: Please provide the PDF in question for inspection.

Comment: it's under copyright, can I provide you some information?

Comment: Do you not have some uncritical PDF you also have that issue with? The required information are a) which boxes are defined in the PDF dictionary of the page in question and b) where and how those crop marks are defined.

Comment: Do you clip your content at cropbox level? See my answer at the question you mentioned above.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't an uncritical one a) can you please tell me how can I read PDF dictionary of the page?sorry probably for the stupid question b) I don't have this information right now, I'm gonna ask

Comment: Did you try iPDFdev's code from his blog? It is mentioned in his answer to the other question. You should also post 2 screenshots, with the bad and good display so we can see the difference. The confidential information can be redacted.

Comment: The easiest way to make sure the crop box is correct is to open it in Adobe Reader on Mac or Windows (yes, there are other good viewers, but Adobe Reader is commonly available and I know it's good). What you see in Adobe Reader is the area defined by the crop box. So if that is good (to your taste), all you have to do is figure out how to display that correctly in your code (probably using iPDFdev's hints). If that doesn't look good, your PDF doesn't define a good crop box and you'll need a bigger hammer :)

Comment: Adobe Reader shows it correctly. Trying @iPDFdev solution is working! thanks everybody for the very useful comments. Waiting for the answer so I can accept it

Comment: another issue...I can see everything fine except for the cover...Adobe  shows it correctly too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those markings are drawn outside the visible page area, the crop box. Since you do not clip the content at page boundary, everything in the page content is displayed.
Add this before drawing the page and the crop marks will no longer be visible.

```
CGContextAddRect(ctx, cropBoxRect);
CGContextClip(ctx);
```

If the cover is still not shown correctly please post in a comment the values for /MediaBox, /CropBox and /Rotate entries and I'll build a test PDF file.

Comment: how can I get /MediaBox, /CropBox and /Rotate entries? thanks

Comment: CGPDFPageGetBoxRect method for media box and crop box and CGPDFPageGetRotationAngle for rotation.

Comment: sorry I thought that you needed something else, here they are, values for the cover page, that still doesn't display correctly: MediaBox: origin=(x=596.126, y=42.5197) size=(width=481.894, height=680.315); CropBox:origin=(x=596.126, y=42.5197) size=(width=481.894, height=680.315); Rotate: 0

Comment: I built a test file using the values above but it was displayed correctly. Unless you can extract the cover page from your document and make it available for download, there is nothing else I can do to help. You can use Adobe Acrobat to extract the cover and also redact confidential information.

Comment: thank you so much @iPDFdev, I'm gonna investigate more while I'm waiting for other test files. I accept your answer in the meanwhile and eventually ask for your kind help again